How to disable one thread out of 3 using fork join_any and fork join_none
I have got an interview question.
We have 3 threads and only one thread should kill and other threads should complete using fork_join, join_any, join_none. How do you do that?
Generally using semaphore or events we can disable the fork but it will kill all processes.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It may be helpful in this case to research the topic and give your own answer, even if it is partial, or you are uncertain about it. This additional material will be helpful to people who understand threading, as they will be able to see where things are unclear for you.
